# Pandas group by with list applied to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science

I have a table:

| ID | Component | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 1 | 5 | 20 |
| 2 | 4 | 15 |
| 3 | 6 | 30 |

and I'd like to group by `ID`, creating a column with a dictionary or list as such:

| ID | Grouped |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[4, 10], [5,20]] |
| 2 | [4, 15] |
| 3 | [6, 30] |

I know using

```
df.groupby(['ID']).Component.apply(list).reset_index()
```

will do so for one column but I'm not sure for many columns.

Comment: Do you need convert all columns? Or only some columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(df.groupby(['ID'])[['Component', 'Revenue']]
   .apply(lambda d: d.to_numpy().tolist())
   .reset_index(name='Grouped')
)
```

output:

```
   ID             Grouped
0   1  [[4, 10], [5, 20]]
1   2           [[4, 15]]
2   3           [[6, 30]]
```